# Every array occurence in 2d array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two arrays - grid and pattern

```
const G = [
  [9,9,9,9,9,9]
]
const P = [
  [9,9]
]
```

I want to get every occurrence of P within G. So the output would be something like this:

```
[
    {
        line: 0,
        charAtStart: 0,
        charAtEnd: 2,
    },
    {
        line: 0,
        charAtStart: 2,
        charAtEnd: 4,
    },
    {
        line: 0,
        charAtStart: 4,
        charAtEnd: 6,
    },
    {
        line: 0,
        charAtStart: 6,
        charAtEnd: 8,
    },
    {
        line: 0,
        charAtStart: 8,
        charAtEnd: 10,
    }
]
```

What I've done so far:

```
for(let i = 0, l = G.length; i < l; i++) {
  if(G[i].toString().includes(P[0].toString())) {

    console.log(G[i].toString(), '\n',
                P[0].toString(), '\n',
                G[i].toString().indexOf(P[0].toString())
               )

    availableFirstLines.push({
      line: i,
      charAtStringStart: G[i].toString().indexOf(P[0].toString()),
      charAtStringEnd: (G[i].toString().indexOf(P[0].toString())) + P[0].toString().length - 1
    })
  }
}
```

So I loop through `G`. First of all I check if `P` even exists within `G[0]`. If so I push its indexOf first char and last char. So my output is

```
[
    {
        line: 0,
        charAtStart: 0,
        charAtEnd: 2,
    }
]
```

problem is that it does detect only first occurrence and then move on. Should I have nested loop to get every occurrence?

**Edit**
I accidentally provided wrong output. I've changed it.

Comment: why are the last 2 objects in your output? charAtStart 6 and above would be an indexes outside of your inner array in G?

Comment: Becaue I convert it into string so `,` are also counted. Notice that property of `availableFirstLines` in code is `charAtStringStart`. I probably should called it same in input & output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you need three levels of nested loops:

1. Loop over the values in G
2. Loop over the values in P for each value in G
3. Loop over the G value looking for all occurrences of the P value

The third part can be done with a `while` loop over [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf), setting the `fromIndex` value to just past the start of the previous match:

```js
const G = [
  [9,9,9,9,9,9]
]
const P = [
  [9,9]
]
let availableFirstLines = [];

G.forEach((Gv, Gi) => {
  const Gs = Gv.toString();
  P.forEach(Pv => {
    const Ps = Pv.toString();
    let i, fi = 0;
    while ((i = Gs.indexOf(Ps, fi)) >= 0) {
      availableFirstLines.push({
        line: Gi,
        charAtStringStart: i,
        charAtStringEnd: i + Ps.length - 1
      });
      fi = i + 1;
    }
  })
});
console.log(availableFirstLines);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could recursively do this by using [`.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) and passing through a starting index for each new recurse you do. You will need to recurse for each "line" in your graph:

```js
const G = [
  [9,9,9,9,9,9]
];

const P = [
  [9,9]
];

const findIndexOf = (line, lineArr, innerP, idx = 0) => {  
  const charAtStart = lineArr.toString().indexOf(innerP.toString(), idx);
  const charAtEnd = charAtStart + innerP.toString().length-1;
  if(charAtStart === -1)
    return [];
  
  return [{line, charAtStart, charAtEnd}, ...findIndexOf(line, lineArr, innerP, charAtEnd)];
}

const res = G.reduce((acc, line, i) => 
  [...acc, ...findIndexOf(i, line, P[i])], []);

console.log(res);
```

If you want the pattern to be batched for every row (not just its associated row in the `G` array, you can use an additional inner `.reduce()` method, which will loop the pattern over each row in your graph like so:

```js
const G = [
  [9,9,9,9,9,9],
  [9,9,9,9,9,9]
];

const P = [
  [9,9]
];

const findIndexOf = (line, lineArr, innerP, idx = 0) => {  
  const charAtStart = lineArr.toString().indexOf(innerP.toString(), idx);
  const charAtEnd = charAtStart + innerP.toString().length-1;
  if(charAtStart === -1)
    return [];
  
  return [{line, charAtStart, charAtEnd}, ...findIndexOf(line, lineArr, innerP, charAtEnd)];
}

const res = G.reduce((acc, line, i) => 
  [...acc, ...P.reduce((r, p) => [...r, ...findIndexOf(i, line, p)], [])], []);

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

You only need 1 loop through G, since you said P is going to be a single line array.

Using `indexOf` comparing the G value with the pattern will give you the index of the pattern occurrences.

Then you just need to change your `indexOf` call to start where the last pattern occurrence ends. The second indexOf parameter will take care of that.

This snippet should work, ignoring `,` characters:

```js
var G = [[9,9,9,9,9,9]];
var P = [[9,9]];

var pattern = P[0].join('');
var availableFirstLines = [];

for (let i = 0; i < G.length; i++) {
  var currentArray = G[i];
  var stringArray = currentArray.join('');
  let indexOccurrence = 0;

  while (indexOccurrence != -1) {
    // This will set the index to the the beginning of the pattern occurrence.
    indexOccurrence = stringArray.indexOf(pattern, indexOccurrence);

    if (indexOccurrence != -1) {
        availableFirstLines.push({
          line: i,
          charAtStart: indexOccurrence,
          charAtEnd: indexOccurrence + pattern.length
        });

        // This will make sure to ignore the previous encountered occurrence.
        indexOccurrence += pattern.length;
    }
  }
}

console.log(availableFirstLines);
```

Comment: After fixing type error with `;` inside loop declaration it provide same output as my code. Please also take a look at my edit.

Comment: This is basically not want I meant. The `P` in my code is some kind of pattern that I want to find in `G`. And I always care about only first line therefore I change `P[0]` to string.

Comment: @dopeCode oh sorry, I think I got what you mean now, I updated my answer. It's not the definitive solution but maybe it will help you take the right track.